# google sheets api from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-sheets-api

I'm trying a simple google sheets api code done in JAVA and run it from AWS Lambda function and I got a timeout error like this

> 2018-04-20 01:55:01.573:INFO::Started SocketConnector@localhost:35315
>   Please open the following address in your browser:
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=523391452358-5o611gt4igv3nik2blim3kr3q2m690sl.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:35315/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly END RequestId: d495a239-443d-11e8-9619-bd212b7bbf47 REPORT RequestId:
>   d495a239-443d-11e8-9619-bd212b7bbf47  Duration: 60046.56 ms   Billed
>   Duration: 60000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 48 MB
>   2018-04-20T01:55:58.627Z d495a239-443d-11e8-9619-bd212b7bbf47 Task
>   timed out after 60.05 seconds

It seems like Google SDK wants to open the browser for the user to authenticate, but there's no browser in AWS Lambda. Is there another way to authenticate without opening the browser? If i use https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwt-auth will it work?Anyone has any helpful links/ sample that I can use? I'm    not experience programmer really appreciate your help, thank you in advance.

Comment: I have a question. In your situation, each user calls APIs using the client ID and secret of each user? Or each user or user calls APIs using one client ID and secret?

Comment: You should be able to use the API Key to invoke Google Sheets API, without the OAuth token (Unless you are accessing a user's profile private data).

Comment: @Tanaike In my case user calls APIs using one client ID and secret.

Comment: @Ashan, Actually what I'm trying to do, user from my web application will generate a report, then they can click 'export to google sheet' which will call the AWS API Gateway, then AWS lambda function  will export reports to GSheet, for user that has google account,  they should sign in and allow access. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: In this flow, you can obtain the token from frontend, initiating the OAuth flow and use that token to send to the API Gateway to execute the Google API action. It won't be the best user experience, but this is the flow which I see as working.

Comment: Hi @Ashan, thank you for your suggestion. Can you please explain a bit more

Comment: I couldn't understand the situation. Is the number of users only one? I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike more than 1 user, actually I'm also not sure if I answer you correctly. I'm very new to this :'|

Comment: In your situation, several users use the server using each user's client ID and client secret. In that case, the spreadsheet is in each user's Google Drive. Each user create or update own spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, the authorization is required to use APIs for each user's Google using each browser, because of use of POST method. And the scope of ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`` might be required to be changed. If the spreadsheet is in the owner's Google Drive. The authorization has to be done by only owner.

Comment: When a user clicks on the report he will be directed to google login (only once) to authorize this app and then you will receive the tokens which can be forwarded to the backend to create a google doc/modify & etc.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I will try it and update here :)

Comment: Hi @Ashan, do you know how to pass the token received from the url  to send a POST request to the Google server to retrieve the credentials of the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) key in order to avoid using a browser.

> A service account is a special type of Google account intended to represent a non-human user that needs to authenticate and be authorized to access data in Google APIs.